# Abstracting functions in TypeScript causing incompatibility between types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to DRY up some of my redux action creators but am having a hard time with coming up with the proper types. Take this simplified example:

```
export interface SortCollectionAction {
    type: string
    payload: {
        field: string
        direction: string
    }
}

export function sortCollection(type: string, field: string, direction: string): SortCollectionAction {
    return {
        type: type,
        payload: {
            field: field,
            direction: direction
        }
    }
}

const LIST_SORT = 'LIST_SORT'

interface SortListAction extends SortCollectionAction {
    type: typeof LIST_SORT
}

function sortList(field: string, direction: string): SortListAction {
    return sortCollection(LIST_SORT, field, direction) 
}
```

The compiler complains that the type 'string' is not assignable to '"LIST_SORT"'. What would be the right way to express the above?

Should I be using generics or casting the return value or is there a more straight-forward way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think I love the fact that there are at least three ways to do what you're trying to do above, that you can pick between based on other factors. I either love it, or it bothers me. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `type` field is going to have any number of values, it should be of type `string`. You can make `LIST_SORT` a string like this:

```
const LIST_SORT: string = 'LIST_SORT';
```

[On the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZWhgGEIAbM4bGBCJAQWtqTgG8AoOLuGATzGAAuOAGcYUZAHNO3MJl5kImACbCO3DXHQJgZVaPFSZmuMoRQqNOsLESk0jQF92z9qEiwtAVyRM6oolIKS2YACj4BG0N7ABotHT0ou0k4sws-JCSpAEphQlggygzGKxZ1bgsYLygy400IoR5+YBi6jTkFJX1ykw1tXX1+vVbezTSQ61NzCaQ27mcnF3Z2bDoxOAAZAEl8ABUAfXwAeQAlXaz7OABeOABybb3D093b5eRUDBw8fJgNhDESsw4KBUEhlCICIFyEVSoD-D0mpFEcAIOhNjsDsczkt2OgfBkArA-mJQkN9LYpKlphkLpJcpCif8YHDahpKtUWCIocEMqEHpjnnEyVT0qVsnAXEA).

If you're going to constrain `type` so that it can only be one of a set of values, you probably want a [string enum](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) instead:

```
enum ListType {
    LIST_SORT = 'LIST_SORT',
    // ...
}
```

Then you'd use `ListType` for the `type` field.

[On the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwDIEsDOMAqAnmMHAN4BQc1mAkgMr4D69A8gEr5wC8cA5BgbM2nPgBoqNAPRS4AOgUUAvhQqhIsOFkQxgUAGYBDAMal60GAGEIAGxvBjMLBEQBBR88TlJ1GMWAAXJi4BP4+cGCGhDYQhgAmQZQ0yXD6WMA2CXB4UNoA5uHJcVhQDk4uQTn54SoqauAWqciIHi7ZFtZ2ZZ4AFH4kQdh4RCRiqemZlTC5iHljxaWtiFMzeQCUQeawnfZL7uVeSTSlMMhQh4U0-YFw1xIpNJHRsVlHD8lpGVmfmffvRSVuhU4AsgYhLtQVMlaqptLoDCYzBYhjB9p4ECBdIg4jg4FsrLZdgc0W03rd-IMQiNgHJBIwWBx8MpVPpmkt2rAUT0flkqrN5oClit8hs8ciQiSLskTmcvDgOoSwT0UdTaUIGZwxjyBYsDms4MogA).

Comment: I was going to suggest sprinkling some generic type parameters to preserver the string literal type. This also works, really depends how important preserving it is for the use case..

Comment: Ex: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZWhgGEIAbM4bGBCJAQWtqQB4AVOUVJAEwGc4fGFGQBzAHxwA3gCg48uDACeYYAC44bOQrCYlZCJh4bZCs3HQJgZY4OFjt5uDwRQqNOhqEikox3ABfGSCZUEhYCwBXJCY6QSJSCndmdk4Qbn47HwkACmVVDTYAGgsrGy97XxKXN1ikCuyASg1CWETKOsYPVjZJUwU3GEioJGl-M3z1RRVgIvGdPQMjE3mnS2tbdZs5pyca5M9nVwOkVcD-IJDsOiE4ABkASXw2AH18AHkAJQ4AXjgAckezzeXzY-xkMmQqAwODwrRgdwQQi6zDSGQE8PaJxRdBYkwg6HuT1eH2+fWCEPQ0Tq8VgiKEOS2tm8YmqxzqDTEzQIRHpMBxo368kGw1GfAS5A63RyQJJoJKTLZtW6jTgwSAA

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - Cool, would be keen to see an answer with your take!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That really helps. I'm confused as to why `const LIST_SORT = 'LIST_SORT';` doesn't automatically cast that as a string. E.g. why the explicit ': string' is necessary if this is a string assigned to a constant.

Comment: In fact, ESLint complains that the `:string` annotation should be removed because it's "trivially inferred".

Comment: @user1032752 - The inferred type of `const LIST_SORT = 'LIST_SORT'` is the [string literal type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) `'LIST_SORT'`. That inference can be widened to `string` in some cases ([example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUAPAXIgzlAJxjAHMBKHANzhgBNEBvAKEVcQgVzgBsBTAOm5wSmMgG4mAXyYcw+RABkAkgGUAKgH0VAeQBKaxAF5EAcmXqtetSYkp05zTv3igA)) but apparently not in your case as we can see from the fact changing it makes TS happy. :-) I have to say I don't know the rules governing that. :-|

Comment: @user1032752 - The fact it doesn't always work suggests that ESLint's rule is slightly optimistic. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Makes sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to preserve the string literal type, your best approach would be to add a generic type parameter to `SortCollectionAction` and `sortCollection`.

```
export interface SortCollectionAction<T extends string> {
    type: T
    payload: {
        field: string
        direction: string
    }
}

export function sortCollection<T extends string>(type: T, field: string, direction: string): SortCollectionAction<T> {
    return {
        type: type,
        payload: {
            field: field,
            direction: direction
        }
    }
}

const LIST_SORT = 'LIST_SORT'

interface SortListAction extends SortCollectionAction<typeof LIST_SORT> {
}

function sortList(field: string, direction: string): SortListAction {
    return sortCollection(LIST_SORT, field, direction) 
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZWhgGEIAbM4bGBCJAQWtqQB4AVOUVJAEwGc4fGFGQBzAHxwA3gCg48uDACeYYAC44bOQrCYlZCJh4bZCs3HQJgZY4OFjt5uDwRQqNOhqEikox3ABfGSCZUEhYCwBXJCY6QSJSCndmdk4Qbn47HwkACmVVDTYAGgsrGy97XxKXN1ikCuyASg1CWETKOsYPVjZJUwU3GEioJGl-M3z1RRVgIvGdPQMjE3mnS2tbdZs5pyca5M9nVwOkVcD-IJDsOiE4ABkASXw2AH18AHkAJQ4AXjgAckezzeXzY-xkMmQqAwODwrRgdwQQi6zDSGQE8PaJxRdBYkwg6HuT1eH2+fWCEPQ0Tq8VgiKEOS2tm8YmqxzqDTEzQIRHpMBxo368kGw1GfAS5A63RyQJJoJKTLZtW6jTgwSAA)

It really depends what you plan to do later with `type` if this added complexity is worth it.